Cannot Load Encryption DLL from a MVC app
I'm testing out some new apps and ran into an odd one. Data connects perfectly when apps are running on a classic application pool, but it blows out with Cannot load encryption DLL C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin32\dbrsa17.dll: version mismatch if it's on integrated. This app uses Owen and that throws the toys out if classic is used.
Any idea what's going on here, and how I can fix it? It does seem odd that it's looking for dbrsa17.dll in the bin32 directory when I'm fairly sure it's the 64-bit version of SQL Anywhere that is running.

Turns out that the DefaultAppPool was corrupt and thinking it was running a 32 bit app - created a new Integrated one, moved the MCV app over to that one and it ran.
